# pyOWM not getting expected result

Tags: python, api, openweathermap

I tried to implement the following code after getting my API key:

```
import pyowm
owm = pyowm.OWM('API key')
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
Forecast = mgr.forecast_at_place('London', '3h').forecast

max_temperature=[]
min_temperature=[]
days=[]


for i in range(0,5):
    day = Forecast.get(i)    

    days.append(day.reference_time('date'))
    max_temperature.append(day.temperature["temp_max"])
    min_temperature.append(day.temperature["temp_min"])
```

The *get()* method is supposed to return a *Weather* object which is stored in the variable *day*.
But I can't access any of the parameters or methods of the *Weather* class.
Even though when I try to print the datatype of *day* using the statement *print(type(day))*, the terminal displays *<class 'pyowm.weatherapi25.weather.Weather'>* suggesting that day is indeed a *Weather* object.

Any suggestions what should be done?

Answer (score 0):

PyOWM maintainer here!

Take a look at the docs for examples about what properties/methods you can invoke on the `Weather` object you have inside `day`:
https://pyowm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/v3/code-recipes.html#observed-weather

Or if you prefer the documentation for the `Weather` class, you can find it here: https://pyowm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyowm.weatherapi25.html#module-pyowm.weatherapi25.weather